# Using css modules in react doesn't affect anything

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm just starting to learn React

I am trying to use .module.css model, but it doesn't connect any element to the class I want.
In my case "React Meetups" must get at least red.

As I saw previously other's mistakes were that they forgot to rename css file, but I hope I got it right

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhRwo.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffCQv.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvjMM.png
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a great site for helping folks with specific programming issues. Unfortunately, your question as posted isn’t really aligned for this site. Best to read up on what’s expected here, then edit your question to include specific code questions. [Start here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Your code and everything else looks fine though